# How to diagnose loss curve not converging?

Tags: model-evaluation, lstm

I am trying to predict remaining useful life (RUL) from temporal data with multilayered LSTM and obtaining the following curve:

[image]

Looks like after first several epochs performance stops to improve and starts oscillating. Is it known situation?

Answer (score 2):

Two options are most likely:

- Your learning rate is  too high to further improve. Try decreasing it by 2-10 times and see what happens. Potentially using a learning rate scheduler is beneficial  - start with high learning rate but decrease it after a few epochs.
- You don't have enough capacity in the network or you are not inputting things correctly. Hard to say without knowing more details and seeing the code